# CSV Conversion Does not recognize special characters

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

Here is the issue. I have a java program which converts an `XML` to `CSV`. One of the element tag from my xml is shown below.

```
<person-name>Greg kaménez</person-name>.
```

My parser is able to parse it correctly. but after the conversion when I write this to a csv file and open that in mcsft excel, I see `"Greg kamÃ©nez"` as a cell value instead of Greg kaménez.

I have also noted that when I open the same csv file in a text editor within Eclipse IDE, it shows the name correctly "`Greg kaménez`".

here is the snippet through which I am writing a string to a csv:

```
    String csv = ""x","y","Greg kaménez","z"";
    String fileName = "output.csv";
    File csvFile = new File(fileName);
    String jobId = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(csvFile), "UTF-8"));
    writer.append(csv);
    writer.close();
```

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the accented `e` being encoded in two characters, one of which modifies the second.  Because that is order specific, when some applications process those characters out of order, it will create gibberish instead of the correctly accented character.  (We'll need to see the code to troubleshoot exactly what is going on though.)

Comment: set the encoding of both files as utf

Comment: thanks for your response I tried setting encoding of both files to UTF-8 but dint work. I think Flavio is right but his answer couldn't help me either. my program generates the csv file within Eclipse and when I look for this file's properties I see UTF-8 encoding has already been set as default

Answer (score 4):

Excel uses Windows-1252 by default. So, if you want to read your CSV in Excel, use

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(csvFile), "Windows-1252"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`CSV` files have no way to specify which character encoding you have used to write them, so programs like text editors and Excel must try to guess the encoding when reading, or use the system default.

If the text editor is able to correctly show the character, probably you did everything right, but Excel did not correctly guess the character encoding.

When you import the file in Excel, it asks you to specify the original encoding. Choose the right value and you should be able to read the file correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I want to achieve this programmatically not manually.